# Post Multipart File inside model - Restful Angularjs - Spring Server

Tags: angularjs, rest, model, http-headers, multipartform-data

I want to post via Angularjs a file (multipartFile) inside my Model

that is my controller model

```
    $scope.modelDomain = {};
    $scope.modelDomain.id = compose.id;
    $scope.modelDomain.title = compose.title;
    $scope.modelDomain.message = compose.message;
    // a file to upload inside my model
    $scope.modelDomain.file = compose.file;
```

A Angular service:

```
angular.module('SecureApp')
  .service('Publishing', function ($resource) {
    return $resource(
      'http://localhost:8080/ServerApp/rest/secure/domain', 
      {modelDomain:'@modelDomain'}, 
      { 
      save: { 
        method: 'POST', 
        params: {modelDomain:'@modelDomain'},
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
      } 
  });
 })
```

a Spring Server

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/secure/domain", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public BufferPublishing newBuffer(@RequestParam ModelDomain modelDomain, HttpServletRequest request){
        ....
    }
```

a server model

```
public class ModelDomain implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7208838545241745827L;
    Integer id;
    String title;
    String message;
    CommonsMultipartFile file;
```

it doesn't works,
The server side don't catch a client call. 
some advice?